how to set or select the first tab in the top navigation bar in React Native when returning from another menu
how to set or select the first tab in the top navigation bar in React Native when returning from another menu. I have tried with initialRouteName but it doesn't work. Has anyone managed to do it?? Please help
how to set or select the first tab in the top navigation bar in React Native when returning from another menu. I have tried with initialRouteName but it doesn't work. Has anyone managed to do it?? Please help me

Share some current code so we can guide you.

Are you using react-navigation or expo-router?
